# Emacs org-mode, minor details

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I still can find some minor details to optimize my workflow,

Given TODO list with elements like:

```
- [ ] task1
- [ ] task2
```

and I want to introduce a new "- [ ]" line, but "M - Enter" does not produce it (just a "-").

Another thing is how to generate a series of whatever. Think about the command line expansion:
{a..z} or {1..10}. How do I generate all elements:

```
 "a b c d ..."
```

or

```
 "1 2 3 4 ..."?
```

Answer (score 2):

Org-mode binds `org-insert-todo-heading` to `<M-S-return>` which creates new heading with same state as previous level.

`-[ ] foo <cursor>` expands with that command to

```
- [ ] foo
- [ ] <cursor>
```

Works naturally on other heading types as well, e.g.

`** TODO heading1<cursor>` expands with that command to

```
** TODO heading1
** TODO <cursor>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post two separate questions next time. It's more productive.

### First question

This isn't an issue in the [newest org-mode](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#keeping-current-with-Org-mode-development)

### Second question

I've been playing around with code that does exactly that.
I've published it just now at https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny.

The default global binding for `tiny-expand` from that code is <kbd>C-;</kbd>.
Here are some expandable templates:

```
m10
m5 10
m5,10
m5 10*xx
m5 10*xx&x
m5 10*xx&0x&x
m25+x?a&c
m25+x?A&c
m97,122stringx
m97,122stringxx
m97;122stringxupcasex
m10+3*100x
m\n10expx
```

You just enter these (sometimes) few chars, and <kbd>C-;</kbd> with the cursor at the end
of the expression.
The expressions are replaced accordingly to

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
5 6 7 8 9 10
5,6,7,8,9,10
25 36 49 64 81 100
19 24 31 40 51 64
0x19 0x24 0x31 0x40 0x51 0x64
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh,ii,jj,kk,ll,mm,nn,oo,pp,qq,rr,ss,tt,uu,vv,ww,xx,yy,zz
aA;bB;cC;dD;eE;fF;gG;hH;iI;jJ;kK;lL;mM;nN;oO;pP;qQ;rR;sS;tT;uU;vV;wW;xX;yY;zZ
3 103 203 303 403 503 603 703 803 903 1003
1.0
2.718281828459045
7.38905609893065
20.085536923187668
54.598150033144236
148.4131591025766
403.4287934927351
1096.6331584284585
2980.9579870417283
8103.083927575384
22026.465794806718
```

I don't know if you or other people will find it useful, but it's useful for me,
and it's costs just 5 minutes to publish it. So have a look if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is regarding your second question (about series):

```
(defun series (from to &optional delimit step formatter)
  (interactive "nSeries left bound: \nnSeries right bound: ")
  (let (delimiter step)
    (if (null current-prefix-arg)
        (setf delimiter " " step (if (< from to) 1 -1)
              formatter #'number-to-string)
      (setf delimiter (read-string "Delimit with: " ", ")
            step (read-number "Increment by: " 1)
            formatter
            (let ((minibuffer-completing-symbol t))
              (eval (read-from-minibuffer
                     "Number to string function: "
                      "#'char-to-string" read-expression-map t
                     'read-expression-history)))))
    (insert
     (mapconcat formatter
                (loop for i = from then (+ i step)
                      with tester = (if (< step 0) #'>= #'<=)
                      while (funcall tester i to)
                      collect i)
                delimiter))))
```

Oh, I've not seen what abo-abo has posted. Anyways, will leave it here as an alternative.